# The holy spirit since Jesus ascended?

Tags: trinity, gospel-of-john

The below two (of numerous) passages are understood by most to be the Holy Spirit coming to guide us after Jesus ascends.

John 16:7

> Nevertheless, I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I **go away,** for if I do not go away, the Helper will not come to you. But if I go, I will send him to you.

John 16:12-13

> <sup>**12**</sup> I still have many things to say to you, but you cannot bear them now. <sup>**13**</sup> When the **Spirit of truth comes,** he will guide you into all the truth, for he will not speak on his own authority, but whatever he hears he will speak, and he will declare to you the things that are to come.

1. Has the Holy Spirit come yet & where is the evidence?
2. Why did Jesus need to leave before the Holy Spirit comes, noting that the Holy Spirit was here since the beginning and throughout?

Comment: Like the answer that you got, from a Catholic perspective, you should get a multitude of answers that can't all be correct without narrowing down to who you're asking.

Comment: I notice that you overwrote the helpful edit that corrected your failures in properly capitalization, and other errors.   Improving other people's posts is good form, deliberately making them worse is not good form.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I amended it as I couldn’t see it being opened - not sure how long it takes for it to be decided, I’m happy for it to be edited to be made suitable

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting question.  I made a small correction here and there.

Comment: not sure if a decision has been made on the edit, I will take it as it’s not going to be opened and delete shortly

Answer (score 1):

I think different denominations will answer this question differently. From a Roman Catholic perspective I would say:

1. Yes.

1b: with the words of the Catechism, paragraph 688:

> The Church, a communion living in the faith of the apostles which she transmits, is the place where we know the Holy Spirit:
>
> - in the Scriptures he inspired;
> - in the Tradition, to which the Church Fathers are always timely witnesses;
> - in the Church's Magisterium, which he assists;
> - in the sacramental liturgy, through its words and symbols, in which the Holy Spirit puts us into communion with Christ;
> - in prayer, wherein he intercedes for us;
> - in the charisms and ministries by which the Church is built up;
> - in the signs of apostolic and missionary life;
> - in the witness of saints through whom he manifests his holiness and continues the work of salvation.

( https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P1Z.HTM )

Or to put it simple: the Holy Spirit guides us very clearly in all three sources of revealed truths catholics know: Holy Scripture, Tradition, the living Magisterium.

But as I said, this is a catholic answer. I can imagine most non-catholic christians will not accept this answer as anything but a curious catholic thing.

Comment: @ ABM K - with apologise I have added c & d, not sure if that changes your answer in anyway.  Noted your A - but is there actual evidence its the HS guiding us - like Jesus done miracles before others.  If it was the HS why then different denominations, everyone would be guided to the 'correct' way.

Comment: :) I am afraid I can’t answer that on a basis outside my personal believes. As you may guess, I think anyone who isn’t catholic isn’t completely listening to the HS. I assume other denominations have similar views. There is no scientific proof the HS said X or Y, outside faith.

Comment: thanks noted - the Q has been closed, but I have edited to a Trinitarian response as I already have your view – albeit it is nice to have diffrent views

Comment: If I may suggest: “trinity” is still the vast majority of christianity and dozens of not hundreds of denominations. You really should be a bit more specific.

Comment: not sure how I would refine it - just wanted a general opinion on how the HS has influenced since Jesus - if you have any possible suggestion - happy for you to edit.

Comment: Well, you might want to specify your question towards catholicism, sola scriptural protestantism, evangelicals, and so on

Comment: If you are going to offer the Catholic perspective, I suggest citing the passage where the tongues of flame descended upon the Apostles. That is a core scriptural support/aspect of the Holy Spirit manifesting in the Catholic tradition.

Comment: Good suggestion for context. But as far as I read the question not a direct answer to the question, so I did not add it.